# "IF" Condition For a Empty Array

Tags: python, arrays

I write a code to give 5 numbers and save them in an array but grades are between 0-20
how to write conditions in for loop without saving any false number

**Basic Code:**

```
import numpy as np
grade=np.zeros(5)
for item in range(len(grade)):
                    grade[item]=float(input("Inser grade:"))
print(f"list of grade : {grade}")
mingrade=lambda grade:np.amin(grade)
maxgrade=lambda grade:np.amax(grade)
print("min Grade is :",mingrade(grade))
print("max grade us :",maxgrade(grade))
```

**now I add condition:**

```
import numpy as np
grade=np.zeros(5,dtype=float)
grade[0]=float(input("Inser grade:"))
if grade[0] < 20 :
                    for item in range(1,len(grade)):
                                     if grade[0] and grade[item] < 20:
                                             grade[item]=float(input("Inser grade:"))
print(f"list of grade : {grade}")
mingrade=lambda grade:np.amin(grade)
maxgrade=lambda grade:np.amax(grade)
print("min Grade is :",mingrade(grade))
print("max grade us :",maxgrade(grade))
```

result is:
Inser grade:15
Inser grade:13
Inser grade:20
Inser grade:23
Inser grade:25
list of grade : [15. 13. 20. 23. 25.]

I need to code dont save any higher of 20

Thanks , im new in python

No accept and save number higher of 20

Comment: I recommend you start again from 0 (delete what you have so far). Don't use numpy yet and try with a simple list, which will make it easier. What you want is 1) Initialize an empty list. 2) Iterate 5 times 3) inside each iteration you want to ask the user for a number, and check if the value is correct. Now implement this from zero and explain to your [rubber duck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281270/what-does-rubber-duck-mean-in-debug-help) what is does line by line.

Comment: You may want to organize your loop like this: `grades = []`, and then `while len(grades) < 5:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big issue is that you are doing a check on the first item in the grade list:
`if grade[0] < 20`

with this as long as someone enters the very first grade correctly (less than 20) then this will continue to accept other inputs.

If I understand your question correctly, you do not want a user to be able to input anything greater than 20. It's not clear if the program should exit, throw it away or ask for it again.

But what would likely work here is to do a for loop with a while loop that validates if the input is valid.
something like this:

```
last_input = 0
for item in range(0, len(grade)):
    while last_input <= 0 or last_input > 20:
        last_input = float(input("Insert grade:"))
        if last_input > 20:
            print("input must be less than or equal to 20")
    grade[item] = last_input
    last_input = 0
```

effectively what this does is it starts to iterate over the grade list that was created at first with 5 zeros, then it tests the input inside the while loop by setting a tracking variable (last_input) to the user's input. As long as the input is below or equal to 20 it will move on to the next item in the loop. If not it will continue to ask the user to re-input the grade. Once a user added a acceptable input it will reset the last input to 0 after recording the user's input and grab the next input.

This is only one way of handling this.

Also, you may want to simplify the for loop by creating an empty list instead of creating a list of 5 zeros

```
grade = []
```

and then in the for loop specify how many times it should iterate

```
for item in range(0, 5):
```

Then instead of setting the value at an index with `grade[item] = last_input` append the value instead with
`grade.append(last_input)`

Comment: one more thing: Your question asks about an empty array. This may be a little nitpicky but your list in your original code is not empty. It is an array containing five float numbers (all zero).  It's not important to the specific answer, but it is a design decision you should consider. 

Should an array containing student's grades ever have a default value of 0? Probably not because that could lead to some weird downstream issues in your system somewhere where maybe it does not overwrite the zero and gives a student an undeserved zero. 

Just a little extra to think about.

Comment: Thanks For Answer my Question, actually best choice is np.empty(5) . other thing no exist do while in python :)